Who is the narrator in "the mirror"
I was watching Andrej Tarkovsky's masterpiece The Mirror and asked myself who the narrator was.
Knowing that this movie is very autobiographical of Tarkovsky I thought that the narrator might be himself
Does anyone know? I couldn't find any "narrator" in the credits

Innokentiy Smoktunovskiy ... Aleksei (voice) ?

If you refer to the poetry, then it's being read by Arseny Tarkovsky, a famous poet and the father of the director. This information is in the opening credits of the movie and Arseny reads his own poetry.
If you refer to the voice of the character who for instance calls his mum or argues with Maria then it the voice of Innokenty Smoktunovsky. He never appears physically in the whole movie as far as I know.  
